# Feedback on which property is making my Apache Nifi processor invalid (a generic question)

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm starting to learn Nifi. I tried setting up some processors and most of the time I'm missing something I was supposed to know.

I already know the properties in bold font are required. Though, that is not enough to realize what is wrong in my settings or properties.

I would like to see a log or any feedback that could point me "this property is incorrect" or something like that.

Is that possible?

Comment: In what context? Most properties have validation built in and you won't be able to start the processor if the validation fails - you will see a warning in the GUI and it will tell you what is wrong. If your value passes validation, but causes an error during run time, you will see a big red bulletin that gives you log fragments. You can also see stacktraces in the nifi-app.log

Comment: For debugging, you can right click on Queues to get to a list of all the flowfiles in the queue, then you can display the content and attributes of each flowfile. You can do this before and then after each processors to get an idea of what changed. You can also see the provenance information which will give some insights.